# How do I show multiple screens in an Quiz app without duplicating activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am complete noob at Android development and I want to get better by building a real-world quiz application. I have some very high level questions:

1. One quiz screen has one question and five answers. This is created using one activity. Now I want the user to navigate to the next screen which is just the next question and so on and so forth.
2. Do I create a new activities per question or do I switch the content using the same activity? How do I do this?

The content resource is an XML feed - so how do I help the user navigate from question screen to question screen?

Comment: post what you have tried ?

Comment: Have a look at this guide: [Using `ViewPager` for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create an other activity. Just change the content of the Views on Next Button's Click.

Suppose you are displaying the Question on `TextView` , then just change the Text of it on next click event. The same things apply for answers also.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [Fragments approach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no reason to have multiple activities for the specific example you describe.

If you have a specific limit on question length and answer length (and number of answers) you can lay out a single xml that has those `TextView`s ready to be populated and then you can dynamically fill in the values as you move from question to question. If you want to get extra snazzy with it, add a `ViewFlipper` and inflate that layout at run time into the flipper and add an animation to get the user to have a more fluid experience as they go from question to question.

I do think this question is a tad too broad and you should start actually coding the app and ask more specific questions as you run into trouble (which you may not).

Answer (score 1):

I think don't go for Multiple Activity for representing different question.

In your main.xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_Layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

just inflate a view that you want to represent and add to this LinearLayout.
After answer one question simply delete the inflated view and again inflate the new view and so on.

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view= (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.question1, null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(view, p);
```

In Activity class on next question button click

do like this
/** it will remove all the view that you inflated.

```
layout.removeAllViews();
```

This is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create new Activity. Just change the content of the page.